# Same module/package for Bower and npm

Tags: node.js, module, package, npm, bower

Is there a way to write a **single** module/package that can be posted both to **npm** and **Bower**, without having to duplicate files?

Imagine you have a simple JS file with some code that is self-contained (i.e. it doesn't have any external dependencies).

An ideal directory would look something like:

```
/file.js
/package.json
/bower.json
```

The problem in this case is that "file.js" to work with npm would need a `module.exports` statement, whereas this would not work with Bower.

So, is there a way to avoid producing two separate almost identical files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems the best option so far (inspired by the Angular team).

Create an `index.js` file in the project root, with this content:

```
module.exports = require('your-original-module.js');
```

Then, in `package.json` add this line:

```
"main": "index.js",
```

Simple, but effective!

Answer (score 0):

If your module doesn't depend on other npm modules,
you can provide file (lets call it 'bowerify.js') with

```
window.MyUtility = require('./file');
```

to expose your utility as global variable.

And then use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to package your code for the browser:

```
src: 'bowerify.js',
dest: 'my_bower_module.js'
```

Now you can install my_bower_module.js with bower.